# How to calculate Signal to noise ratio in a completely dark image

Tags: image, camera, camera-calibration, noise, canon-sdk

I am working on a high school scientific paper where I am trying to show the impact of heat on CCD and CMOS cameras. I have "completely" black pictures taken in different temperatures (The camera is enclosed in a completely light-sealed environment) and as they are completely black there should only be luminance values of 0. Is there any really easy way of just picking out the values that are above 0 and treat that at noise?, maybe with a simple Python code? Should I also value higher value noise in a linear or exponential way?

I am using a Canon 500d which spits out Canons raw format, I am also interested in trying it with my Nikon d5300 which spits out .NEF files

Any help is welcome

Found a program called FIJI which I tried to get help me extract the SNR, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Any half decent image processing program will let you look at the baseline signal to noise of a dark frame by showing a histogram of the values. Various programs intended for astronomers will let you determine the SNR and any bias in the sensor. It is likely that there will be a warm corner where the readout electronics reside.    Stretching the histogram 10x or 100x brighter will show you most of it.  Try for example the free download of eg Paintshop Pro. Irfanview would do for a quick look. This looks like about the best bet [FITS viewr](https://arnholm.org/astro/software/ImageTOOLSca/)